# Excel formula to find Max and return a column from the matching row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks some thing like this:

| Product 1 | Date | Site1_Sales | Site2_Sales | Site2_Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 1-Jan | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| x2 | 2-Jan | 60 | 51 | 150 |
| X1 | 2- Jan | 110 | 30 | 40 |

There will be 1000s of rows with repeated Product but with unique dates. This is  what I would like to find:

1. What was the Max sales for a product ? and  on which date ?  I tried using Maxifs but it ends up with value error it looks it can handle only continuous ranges.
2. What was the sum of sales for a product for specific period e.g first 10 days ?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. see “Remarks” about #value error:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883

2. SUMIF works in the same way as MAXIF (e.g. you could use a start date and end date as multiple criteria)
3. FILTER should help you to find the date(s) of max. Sales as well

Comment: I am looking for a formula.

Comment: MAX (FILTER the 3 data columns as a range against Product as filter criteria)

Comment: To find the date it should work like this with the FILTER function: use date column as range, filter criteria is a combination of product AND (Sales1=maxSales OR Sales2=maxSales OR Sales3=maxSales)

Comment: maxSales is the value you calculated for the specific product with the first formula.

Comment: Also in the FILTER function, use  * for AND and + for OR  when you combine the criteria